# How to create an insert trigger based on primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am stuck on a problem creating a trigger in SQL Server. I have `MyTable` with the following columns (simplified):

- `Sn` - Identity, not nullable;
- `SomeId` - int, not nullable;
- miscellaneous other columns

The `Sn` column is nothing special, values 1,2...n.

`SomeId` needs to be `1000 + Sn`, i.e. this is what I want the trigger to do on insert.

The problem I am having is a standard trigger fails if I don't include something for `SomeId` (error is that null is not allowed), if that trigger is using `after insert`. Maybe I am meant to use `instead of insert`, but I am having trouble getting that to work correct or find details about it.

The other factor here - I am not even sure if it is possible for what I am trying to do to work. I.e when a new row is being created and SQL Server generates an `Sn` (Identity column), can a trigger be part of that process and also compute the `SomeId` value (which needs the `Sn` value) before inserting?

If not, as a fallback I could either make the `SomeId` column nullable (not desirable), or always insert 0 into it (and let the trigger fire afterwards to update it), but that would be a bit grim also.

Comment: Do you really need a trigger? A computed column sounds more appropriate.

Comment: Sounds like you want a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Also - what's benefit of having practially identical values? Your rows will have (1, 1001), (2, 1002), (3, 1003) - why do you need that second number? Seems superfluous .... You could easily just `SELECT Sn + 1000` in a query when you need that value - why compute and store it ?

Comment: I think you have an You have an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem): I would create a view with that column added, like `create view myview as select *, Sn + 1000 as SomeId from mytable`

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the comments. The example I gave was an oversimplification to demonstrate what I am trying to solve. In reality, 'SomeId' is an end-user visible number (the PK wouldn't be), 7 digits long. The concept is that this is set initially by our system, then the user gets to modify it (eg put a prefix on it); I won't go into reasons why. So therefore it is to be computed only once.
I agree, frigging this via code or sql is trivial, just that the request was for a trigger. (And it was easy in Firebird, lol)

Answer (score 0):

No need for a trigger.  Just use a SEQUENCE to generate the ID values instead of an IDENTITY column, eg

```
create sequence seq_MyTable
start with 1
increment by 1 

go

CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
     Sn     int not null primary key default (next value for seq_MyTable),
     SomeID int not null unique default (next value for seq_MyTable) + 1000,
     Name  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

insert into MyTable(Name)
values ('A'),('B'),('C')

select * from Mytable
```

Comment: Sounds perfect! Exactly what I was looking for, cheers